# Intersection points Point1.Y and Y should be equal. But there is a difference in Point1.Y and Y. WHY?

Tags: c++, math, geometry, precision, intersection

Suppose we have two lines.

> L1: y1 = m1.x1 +c1 
> L2: y2 = m2.x2 +c2 
> such that m1 != m2

> intersection_X = (c2 - c1) / (m1 - m2) 
> intersection_Y = m1 * intersection_X + c1

Also, if we calculate **intersection_Y** w.r.t **L2** i.e. **intersection_Y = m2 * intersection_X +c2**
Both the **intersection_Y** should be equal.
If you run the below code and check **point1.Y** and **Y**, you'll find that both are **not equal**.
 I think there is something wrong with the precision handling here. 
Because of this difference, crash is happening.
Can some one throw light, please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<limits>

using namespace std;

#define FUZZ_GEN (1e-9)       //tolerance for vertical check
#define FEQUAL(a, b, fuzz)  (fabs(a - b) <= (fuzz))

struct Point {
    double X, Y;
};

class LineSegment {            //Line class

public:
    LineSegment(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);

    void IntersectionPoints(LineSegment side);        

    double X1, Y1, X2, Y2, M, C;
};

LineSegment::LineSegment(double fX1, double fY1, double fX2, double fY2)   //Constructor for line
    : X1(fX1),
    Y1(fY1),
    X2(fX2),
    Y2(fY2)
{
    if (FEQUAL(X1, X2, FUZZ_GEN))     // if vertical, slope is inf.
    {
        M = C = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();        // slope undefined
    }
    else
    {

        M = (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1);
        C = Y1 - (M * X1);
    }
}
void LineSegment::IntersectionPoints (LineSegment side) {

    Point point1;
    point1.X = (C - side.C) / (side.M - M);     //intersection point 1
    point1.Y = M * point1.X + C;
    
    double Y = side.M * point1.X + side.C;       // ?? Y != point1.Y
}

int main()
{
// data coming from lower level APIs. Can't be changed
    LineSegment side = LineSegment(10.267716536547709,   //create first line
            6.8779527559055005,
            10.031496064106765,
            6.8779527559055005);

    LineSegment line = LineSegment(10.149606299212586,     // create second line
        9.1220472440944818,
        10.149606296983265,
        4.2665936725507594);

    line.IntersectionPoints(side);  //call to calc intersection point 
    return  0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doens't compile on GCC 10.1. https://godbolt.org/z/dejYzG It seems your example is nearly minimum reproducible example. Maybe you may provide the value of 2 Y you found on this question.

Comment: My assumption: there is a small difference between them, because float points do have precision error. They should be almost the same if your algorithm is correct.

Comment: Can you give some examples about that "not equal"? I mean: 2 is not equal than 3 (simply wrong), but 2.00001 is not equal to 2.00002 (right, but some precision error).

Comment: corrected the code. It'll compile now

Comment: Examples of "not equal"
-3e-07 to +3e-07.

I know this is small.

Comment: [Double precision gives from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) worth a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *finite* number of double precision floating point numbers.

This means there are infinitely many real numbers *between* two floating point numbers. There are **huge gaps** between floating point numbers - filled with numbers you cannot represent!

When you define two lines, their intersection point is *very unlikely* to lie exactly on a double precision floating point number. It will lie somewhere in the vast void between the numbers.

Imagine you zoom in so deep that you can see the space between floating numbers clearly. You can visualize the intersection like the following image, where grid lines are the floating point numbers:

[image: Image of two line segments intersecting on a grid]

If the bottom corner here has coordinates x=0 y=0, the x-axis value closest to the intersection is x=2. But if you evaluate the two lines at x=2, for the line C-D  you get y=2, and for the line A-B you get y=3. Why? Because the lines don't intersect at (2,2) or (2,3), they intersect at a point that's in the space between.